# Oracle SQL Objects - Unique/Foreign Key on references

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible to set unique/foreign keys on reference fields when using SQL Objects? For example, assuming I have the following table:

```
create table MY_TABLE (
   SOME_REFERENCE ref MY_TYPE
);
```

Can I set a unique key on a reference? Something like this:

```
alter table MY_TABLE modify (constraint ABC unique(SOME_REFERENCE))
```

(Which gives `ORA-02329: column of datatype REF cannot be unique or a primary key`)

**Is it possible to achive something like unique/foreign keys on reference fields (Maybe by using workarounds?)**

Answer (score 1):

There is the workaround but it's tricky.

```
create type my_type as object 
( id number, v varchar2(20));

create table my_type_table of my_type;

insert into my_type_table values(1,'a');

create table MY_TABLE (
  SOME_REFERENCE ref MY_TYPE
);

create or replace function test_func(p_ref ref MY_TYPE) return number DETERMINISTIC  
is 
  v_typ MY_TYPE;
begin 
  SELECT DEREF(p_ref) INTO v_typ FROM DUAL;
  return v_typ.id;
end; 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fn_idx_un ON MY_TABLE (test_func(SOME_REFERENCE));
```

And test.

```
insert into my_type_table values(1,'a');
insert into MY_TABLE SELECT REF(e) FROM my_type_table e; (*1)
insert into MY_TABLE SELECT REF(e) FROM my_type_table e; (*2)
```

*1 - works fine, and row is inserted.

*2 - execption is raised. ORA-00001: `unique constraint (FN_IDX_UN) violated`

Comment: Thanks, that is what I am looking for! Is there any way to achieve something similar for foreign keys?